# Custom GUI with few lines like AutoHotkey

Tags: bash, software-recommendation, gui

In AutoHotkey (Windows-only scripting tool), it is possible to create thorough graphical user interfaces with very few lines of code. You [create](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gui.htm) a GUI and [add](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GuiControls.htm) or [edit](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GuiControl.htm) its elements. Any element can have a listener installed just using the option [`g-label`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gui.htm#label).

Consider this interface:

[image: ahk gui]

For better understanding, here's the entire AHK source code.

```
gui, color, BADEFA
gui, font, s6 cRed, Verdana
gui, add, text, x150 y5, Hello!
gui, font
gui, add, text, x10 y5, This is a gui.
gui, add, dropDownList, w60 gcolor_selected vselected_color, Black|White|Green||Blue
gui, add, text, xp+70 yp+0 vcolor_prompt w120
gui, add, picture, x10, kitten.png
gui, show, center w300, I am a beatiful GUI
return
color_selected:
    gui, submit, nohide
    guicontrol,, color_prompt, You selected %selected_color%
    gui, font, c%selected_color%
    guicontrol, font, color_prompt
return
```

The above screenshot was made using [WINE](https://www.winehq.org/). I am looking for a language, tool, script which offers similar GUI-functionality like AHK does for Windows, mostly in terms of simplicity. The absolute coordinate syntax (option `x[X] y[Y]`) is the central requirement. The best I could come up with so far is Python's [TkInter](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter), which doesn't even support absolute positioning. Is this the most compact solution there is for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Edit 5 years later:* Instead of the below, I'd now suggest my other project for this, [AHK_X11](https://github.com/phil294/AHK_X11), AutoHotkey for Linux. Several things are still missing, but the above script should work mostly fine.

[image: img]

---

Could not find any, so I did one myself. [Tcl/Tk](https://www.tcl.tk/) is the closest I could find, however it is (as the name suggests) `Tcl` code.

So, it is called [TkBash](https://github.com/phil294/tkbash) and is a bash wrapper around the tcl code. Here is my attempt to recreate the image from the question:

```
#!/bin/bash
tkbash 1 window --theme clam --w 290 -h 200
tkbash 1 --tkcommand ". configure -background lightblue"
tkbash 1 label label1 -x 10 -y 10 -w 80 -h 20 -t "This is a gui."
tkbash 1 label label2 -x 140 -y 10 -w 30 -h 15 -t "Hello!"
tkbash 1 --tkcommand "font create myfont -family Helvetica -size 8"
tkbash 1 label2 --tkcommand "configure -font myfont"
tkbash 1 select select1 -x 10 -y 30 -w 80 -h 20 -t "Black|White|Green||Blue"
tkbash 1 label label3 -x 95 -y 30 -w 120 -h 20
tkbash 1 button button1 -x 245 -y 25 -w 30 -h 30 -t "ok" -c "
    selected_color=\"\$(tkbash 1 get select1)\"
    tkbash 1 label3 -t \"You selected \$selected_color\""
tkbash 1 image image1 -x 10 -y 60 -w 125 -h 120 --image "kitten.png"
```

[image]