# Linux AutoHotKey Wine or Alternative?

Tags: wine, software-recommendation, automation

I want to make the same AutoHotKey GUI for Linux as I have on Win to send keystrokes to the same app under Linux.
Will "WinMenuSelectItem, ahk_class.." work ?
Does Window Spy work to give the ahk_class ?
Or is there something else I can use on Linux to access the app's menus and send keystrokes from a GUI with action buttons and have an always on top option ?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! You'd probably find https://github.com/autokey/autokey helpful. Install with `sudo apt install autokey-gtk`

Comment: There's some more information here: https://askubuntu.com/a/6244/359408

Comment: Some people have had success making AutoHotKey work on Linux with wine: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=5173

Comment: autokey is good but I need a GUI like https://askubuntu.com/questions/943106/custom-gui-with-few-lines-like-autohotkey?rq=1 to send the keystrokes from a button click.